# I am unable to Redirect the URL hiding the directory name

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been Trying to hide the folder name from the URL.
Suppose my domain is example.com which is working absolutely fine.
In the root I have a directory called 'users' where I save folders in the name of users.

Inside user folder I have folders mike, tony, bob which is created dynamically once user subscribe to my site. Each user folder has a index.php file in it.
I am able to access these files if I type the below url:

example.com/users/mike/index.php

example.com/users/tony/index.php

example.com/users/bob/index.php

what I want is to hide the folder name users from the URL. So if I type example.com/users/mike it should redirect to example.com/mike

Can anyone please help me in this.

Comment: Is this for every folder? Or just certain ones?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your site's `DocumentRoot` is set to `root`, you can do ...

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /users/$1/
```

The incoming request will be a URI of `/folder1` which the RewriteRule converts to a URI of `/users/folder1/` and then your DocumentRoot is prepended on the front and, assuming index is enabled, `index.php` is appended to the end to get a FILE name of `root/users/folder1/index.php`.

Comment: I have been Trying to hide the folder name from the URL. Suppose my domain is example.com which is working absolutely fine. In the root I have a directory called 'users' where I save folders in the name of users. Inside user folder I have folders mike, tony, bob which is created dynamically once user subscribe to my site. Each user folder has a index.php file in it.

Comment: I am able to access these files if I type the below url

example.com/users/mike/index.php
example.com/users/tony/index.php
example.com/users/bob/index.php

what I want is to hide the folder name users from the URL.

so if I type example.com/users/mike it should redirect to example.com/mike